# Dedup using SQL on a huge 1 billion data set

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am having out of memory issues while trying to dedup a table consisting of huge amount of data.

Scenario :

```
Column A      |    Column B ( Date )

  Value1            Date1
  Value1            Date2
  Value2            Date3
  Value2            Date4
```

I need to dedup on both these columns, I need to pick the latest record using column b.

Lets say date2 and date4 are the latest dates. My output should be:

```
Column A      |    Column B ( Date )

  Value1            Date2
  Value2            Date4
```

Currently I am using the below query which works. Is there a better way of doing this using less memory.

```
CREATE TABLE UNIQUE_TABLENAME AS (
SELECT a.column a, a.column b, a.column c, a.column d
from tablename a,
(select column a,max(column b) from tablename group by column a)b
where a.column a = b.column a
and a.column b= b.column b)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The usual way to deduplicate is to use row_number. What you are doing here would be superior only if there are very many duplicates.

Comment: @usr yes there are many duplicates in this table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct on (col_a) 
    col_a as value, col_b as "date"
from t
order by col_a, col_b desc
```

Check [distinct on](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Comment: distinct on is not supported on redshift :(